# Recycler View cannot refresh the cards

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I am using `recyclerview` and `cardview` to display details but when i delete a particular row from `sqlite` it remains on the view i don't now where should i code to refresh the `recyclerview` after delete and also after deleting view if i tried to add new details i.e card it does not show up in the view.

And also i tried to implement `radiobutton` when i scroll it changes how to stop that.

I am new to Android and `recyclerview` so i am not aware where to implement codes such as `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `invalidate()` 
so can you guyz help me out with the above stated problem.

MyAdapter class

```
  public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {


static   List<EmployeeDetails> dbList;
static  Context context;
MyAdapter(Context context, List<EmployeeDetails> dbList ){
    this.dbList = new ArrayList<EmployeeDetails>();
    this.context = context;
    this.dbList = dbList;


}


@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.card_item, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.name.setText(dbList.get(position).getName1());
    holder.phone.setText(dbList.get(position).getPhone1());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dbList.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView name,phone;
    public ImageView i,edit,delete;
   // public RadioButton p,a,l;


     DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(MyAdapter.context);


    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);


        i=(ImageView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.empimage);
        name = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.rvname);
        phone = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvphone);

        edit=(ImageView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        delete=(ImageView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

       /* p=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.Present);
        a=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.Absent);
        l=(RadioButton)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.Leave);
  */


        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                        String s=name.getText().toString();
                        EmployeeDetails e=new EmployeeDetails();

                        helper.deleteARow(s);



                    }
                }



        );


    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

class where `Recyclerview` is implemented

```
 public class Employees extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
DatabaseHelper helpher;
List<EmployeeDetails> dbList;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


public Employees() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.employees, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton fab= (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(this);




   //Recycle

    helpher=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    dbList= new ArrayList<EmployeeDetails>();
    dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
   mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),dbList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  //  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   // mRecyclerView.invalidate();
    return rootView;

}



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),addemployee.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Help me with this I searched a lot on internet but i cannot find a proper way

**EDIT**

my db code to retrieve data

```
           public List<EmployeeDetails> getDataFromDB(){
    List<EmployeeDetails> modelList = new ArrayList<EmployeeDetails>();
    String query = "select name,phone_no from "+TABLE_NAME1;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            EmployeeDetails model = new EmployeeDetails();
            model.setName1(cursor.getString(0));
            model.setPhone1(cursor.getString(1));
           // model.setRoll(cursor.getString(2));
            //model.setAddress(cursor.getString(3));
            //model.setBranch(cursor.getString(4));

            modelList.add(model);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to delete the row after clicking on delete image .

okay so call  `notifyItemRemoved(position);` 
inside delete.setOnClickListene(.....).

and also make sure your delete action deletes the entry from dbList instance also else deleted row will be visible after refresh (when you rerun activity or scroll )

if your function `helper.deleteARow(s);`  refreshes dbList then call `notifyItemRemoved(position);` just after `helper.deleteARow(s);` line inside delete.setOnClickListene(.....).

new code:

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    String s=name.getText().toString();
                    EmployeeDetails e=new EmployeeDetails();

                    helper.deleteARow(s);

                   notifyItemRemoved(position);`

                }
            }



    );
```

you can call notifyDataSetChanged()  also but it will refresh all row which is not necessary .

Comment: Thanks for commenting but after updating code as u suggested it says non-Static method  notifyItemRemoved(position);` cannot be reference from a static content

Comment: Yes , you cannot call a non-static inside a static function for that remove static from "public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder......."  to "public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder........"

Comment: I tried it does delete the card but renters it again below...i got error in                    notifyItemRemoved(position); on position so i wrote getAdapterposition() is it correct or the error  is the result to that getAdapterposition()

Comment: as I said , you need to update the dbList also else it will show the row again . (getAdapterposition()  also okay but position is already there .

Comment: i don't think  helper.deleteARow(s);  deleting the element s from dbList .which adapter is using . so please do handle it . reflect your changes to dbList also. I don't know  implementation of  " helper.deleteARow(s); "  but i can guess accroding to function call that it may be changing data of helper but not dbList.

Comment: yes you are right.i must figure out how to update dblist deleteARow  function is just updating the database

Comment: call this dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB() ; again just after helper.deleteARow(s);  if your helper.deleteARow(s) function updates the database accordingly . I did same for cursor and it's working perfectly. so what i did first l deleted the entry from database then reloaded cursor and notifyItemRemoved(position) , you can checkout demo http://pintulalm.me/msplayer/  of row delete using this  method

Comment: well ,Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: when the cards are more if i delete a card and try to enter a new card it doesn't get added otherwise when the cards are few i.e when card don't go out of the screen new card is added without any problem

Comment: here is my code I have used and it's working perfectly for all numbers of items [code ](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o-jYT3BRtPh_BJdVS82sMiOEz47lRYIPabgOwvsuwaA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: may be you need to remove getAdapterposition() and use position provided by view holder ,as position .

Comment: i tried but the problem still exist it happens only after i delete and try to add new card.How to keep the position out of the scope of the onBindViewHolder and use to re add it?

Comment: did you use this  `notifyItemInserted(position);`?

Comment: No ..i called directly datafromdb inside my fragment where recyclerview is implemented ..

Comment: can you show the code ? use private link  you don't want to show everyone

Comment: helpher=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()); dbList= new ArrayList<EmployeeDetails>(); dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB(); 
      I have posted it in my question

Comment: no i mean code of add event .how does this "helpher=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()); dbList= new ArrayList<EmployeeDetails>(); dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB()" adds new item ?

Comment: I have not define add event function to add the item ..i have a second activity where a from is present and it enters the value in database as the button is clicked and i have given intent to open the activity where fragment which implemented recycler view is present .. refer My DB code above

Comment: i don't know how  are you implementing and add event takes action  but if you are using same activity then you have to use notfityDataChanged() or notifyItemInserted(position)  after updating datalist accordingly  else relanuch the activity of fragment or reload fragment.

Comment: I am relaunching the activity item does get added but after deleting any card and if cards are more it stops to add if i delete all cards and then add it gets added may be it doesn't get position or may be it has to do with bind view holder scope i guess

Comment: Sorry that didn't worked btw i am working on my college project to created an attendance management system